# JavaFX - Making ListView of custom made objects editable?

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx

So I've made a simple to-do list using JavaFX. I wish to make each item in the To-do list editable by simply double clicking it and being able to enter new values for the item. I've been reading through JavaDocs to gain a better understanding of how to do this. I found an example online on how to do this with A listview of type String, but it seems to be more complicated when you have a listview of custom made objects (as is the case with me, where the ListView is of type ToDoItem, a class shown later in this post). Here is what I've tried so far.

```
  public void initialize()
    {
        listContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete");
        deleteMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                deleteItem(item);
            }
        });

        listContextMenu.getItems().addAll(deleteMenuItem);
        todoListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TodoItem>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TodoItem> observable, TodoItem oldValue, TodoItem newValue) {
                if(newValue != null)
                {
                    TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    itemDetailsTextArea.setText(item.getDetails());
                    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy");
                    deadlineLabel.setText(item.getDeadline().format(df));
                }
            }
        });

        wantAllItems = new Predicate<TodoItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(TodoItem todoItem) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        wantTodaysItems = new Predicate<TodoItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(TodoItem todoItem) {
                return todoItem.getDeadline().equals(LocalDate.now());
            }
        };
        filteredList = new FilteredList<TodoItem>(TodoData.getInstance().getTodoitems(), wantAllItems);
        SortedList<TodoItem> sortedList = new SortedList<TodoItem>(filteredList,
                new Comparator<TodoItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(TodoItem o1, TodoItem o2) {
                        return o1.getDeadline().compareTo(o2.getDeadline());
                    }
                });

        //todoListView.setItems(TodoData.getInstance().getTodoitems());
        todoListView.setItems(sortedList);
        todoListView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        todoListView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        todoListView.setEditable(true);

        todoListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TodoItem>, ListCell<TodoItem>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<TodoItem> call(ListView<TodoItem> lv) {
                TextFieldListCell<TodoItem> cell = new TextFieldListCell<TodoItem>(){
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if(empty) setText(null);
                        else
                        {
                            setText(item.getShortDescription());
                            if(item.getDeadline().isBefore(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)))
                                setTextFill(Color.RED);
                            else if(item.getDeadline().equals(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)))
                                setTextFill(Color.BROWN);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void commitEdit(TodoItem newValue) {
                        super.commitEdit(newValue);
                    }

                };

                cell.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
                            cell.commitEdit(lv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                    }
                });

                cell.emptyProperty().addListener(
                        (obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) ->
                        {
                            if(isNowEmpty)
                                cell.setContextMenu(null);
                            else
                                cell.setContextMenu(listContextMenu);
                        }
                );

                cell.setConverter(new StringConverter<TodoItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public String toString(TodoItem object) {
                        return object.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TodoItem fromString(String string) {
                        cell.getItem().setShortDescription(string);
                        return cell.getItem();
                    }
                });
                return cell;
            }
        });

        // this is the method where the source of the exception is being reported
        todoListView.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<TodoItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<TodoItem> e) {
                todoListView.getItems().set(e.getIndex(), e.getNewValue());
            }
        });

    }
```

My ListView is of type ToDoItem. Here is what ToDoItem class looks like:

```
public class TodoItem {

private SimpleStringProperty shortDescription;
private SimpleStringProperty details;
private LocalDate deadline;

public TodoItem(String shortDescription, String details, LocalDate deadline) {
    this.shortDescription = new SimpleStringProperty(shortDescription);
    this.details = new SimpleStringProperty(details);
    this.deadline = deadline;
}

public String getShortDescription() {
    return shortDescription.get();
}
public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
    this.shortDescription.set(shortDescription);
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details.get();
}
public void setDetails(String details) { this.details.set(details); }

public LocalDate getDeadline() {
    return deadline;
}
public void setDeadline(LocalDate deadline) {
    this.deadline = deadline;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return shortDescription.get();
}
}
```

The To-Do list UI itself runs and shows on screen without a problem, and all other functionality works (adding item, deleting item etc..). The only thing im having trouble with is making it editable.

Here is the stack trace I get upon pressing ENTER (line 162 refers to the beginning of the setOnEditCommit method and line 165 refers to the single line of code within the handle method):

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:132)
    at com.arslansana.todolist.Controller$7.handle(Controller.java:165)
    at com.arslansana.todolist.Controller$7.handle(Controller.java:162)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.commitEdit(ListCell.java:378)
    at com.arslansana.todolist.Controller$6$1.commitEdit(Controller.java:122)
    at com.arslansana.todolist.Controller$6$1.commitEdit(Controller.java:104)
    at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.lambda$createTextField$615(CellUtils.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:178)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:216)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:246)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, exactly as it is (other than removing the line you have commented is incorrect). What is the actual problem? Can you explain what is happening or not happening that is different to what you expect, and expand the code (should only take a few more lines) so that it forms a [MCVE]?

Comment: By "works fine", I mean it is editable and the edits are propagated back to the backing list in the way you define.

Comment: When I remove the line that gives an error, it runs fine. As in, the GUI to-do list window opens up showing all to-do items and they are clickable, show description, context menu works fine etc. However, it is not editable for me. Double-clicking on an item in the listview does not do anything. I am unable to understand how you were able to edit the listview.

Comment: I've edited my initial post to show my entire initialize method. Ive commented the section of the code where im attempting to make the listview editable.

Comment: Uh, you replace the cell factory that provides the editing with another one that is not editable.

Answer (score 3):

You set the cell factory on the list view to a cell factory that provides cells that support editing:

```
    todoListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TodoItem>, ListCell<TodoItem>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<TodoItem> call(ListView<TodoItem> lv) {
            TextFieldListCell<TodoItem> cell = new TextFieldListCell<TodoItem>();
            // ...

            return cell ;
        }
    });
```

but then you almost immediately replace that with a cell factory that provides non-editable cells:

```
    todoListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TodoItem>, ListCell<TodoItem>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<TodoItem> call(ListView<TodoItem> param) {
            ListCell<TodoItem> cell = new ListCell<TodoItem>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    // ...
                }
            };

            // ...

            return cell;
        }
    });
```

So, of course, the cells in your list view are not editable.

Since a list view has (at most) a single list cell for each item, you need to provide all the functionality you want in a single cell:

```
    todoListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TodoItem>, ListCell<TodoItem>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<TodoItem> call(ListView<TodoItem> lv) {
            TextFieldListCell<TodoItem> cell = new TextFieldListCell<TodoItem>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setStyle("");
                    } else
                        if(item.getDeadline().isBefore(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)))
                            setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red ;");
                        else if(item.getDeadline().equals(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)))
                            setStyle("-fx-text-fill: brown;");
                        else 
                            setStyle("");
                }
            };
            cell.setConverter(new StringConverter<TodoItem>() {
                @Override
                public String toString(TodoItem object) {
                    return object.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public TodoItem fromString(String string) {
                    return new TodoItem(string, null, null);
                }
            });
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Note also that your `updateItem()` method needs to handle all cases (e.g. if the item changes from one that is due tomorrow to one that is not, then the color needs to be removed from the cell's text).

The way your `onEditCommit` is currently implemented, you will get null pointer exceptions as the cell implementation doesn't deal with the deadline being null (but the `onEditCommit` handler sets the deadline to null). I'll leave that for you as I don't know what you really intend to do in that part of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made the necessary changed and the cell is now editable. However, when I press enter to commit the changes something strange happens: a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is thrown, but the cell remains in TextField form. When I click somewhere else to lose focus on it, it changes back ListCell and the changed I made were applied. How can I allow the ENTER key to commit the changes without an exception being thrown?

Comment: I've added my attempt to use the ENTER key to commit in my original post. I used the setOnKeyPressed method. The exception is still thrown in the same way.

Comment: @arslansana I addressed that in the last paragraph of the answer

Comment: If you look at my OP, you'll see I modified my fromString method so it doesn't pass null anymore to create the object, so I don't think thats the problem. The exception im getting is not a nullPointer exception but a UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @arslansana Yes, I didn't notice that change. Try removing the `onEditCommit` handler (which shouldn't be needed with that change). If that doesn't work, add the complete stack trace to the question.

Comment: Firstly, the method im using is setOnEditCommit, not onEditCommit. Nevertheless, removing it did not solve the problem, I got the same exception. I put it back in and have updated my OP to show the full stack trace.

Comment: @arslansana How can that be true? If you remove the call to the method that sets the `onEditCommit` property, you can't still get an exception whose stack trace refers to the code you removed.

Comment: No the stack trace I posted occurs when the setOnEditCommit method still exists. When removed, the UnsupportedOperationException still occurs, except this time it refers to the code creating the new TextFieldListCell and the commitEdit method inside it.

Comment: @arslansana The `UnsupportedOperationException` occurs when you try to set an element on the `SortedList`, which is an unmodifiable list. You really don't need to set that element, because the list already contains that element at the correct location. It's not clear to me if you're referring to the default `commitEdit(...)` method here (which you override but just call the superclass implementation, for some reason), or where you call it from the key pressed handler (which seems unnecessary too).